# Postgresql Update statement

Tags: postgresql, sql-update

I am currently operating with 2 tables: one is a live one and one is a stage one. Above code updates values in the live table using staging table as a source. It only updates values in column "firstname" if the row in the stage table already exists in the live table and some other simple criteria.

```
Update LiveTable
    SET LiveTable.firstname = TestTable.firstname
FROM TestTable
    WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM LiveTable WHERE LiveTable.userid = TestTable.userid)
    AND TestTable.firstname IS NOT NULL
    AND LEN(TestTable.firstname) > len(LiveTable.firstname);
```

Above code jets the job done but takes quite some time. I was wondering if there is any faster way to do it.

I have tries to create FUNCTION to do the same thing, but was not able to get it to work.

Comment: Try `where livetable.userid = testtable.userid` instead of the `where exists (...)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a join between the two tables

```
Update LiveTable
    SET LiveTable.firstname = TestTable.firstname
FROM TestTable
WHERE LiveTable.userid = TestTable.userid
  AND TestTable.firstname IS NOT NULL
  AND length(TestTable.firstname) > len(LiveTable.firstname);
```

The condition  `TestTable.firstname IS NOT NULL` is not really needed because `length(TestTable.firstname) > len(LiveTable.firstname)` will filter out rows where `firstname` is null anyway. And it should be `length()` not `len()`.

Comment: Thanks alot @a_horse_with_no_name It did take me some time to test this bit but it does the job exactly how i want it. Something that used to take a few hours is no taking a few minutes. Is there a reason why this bit is much faster then a regular 'WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 from ....)' statement? Is there any impact on stability/reliability of the outcome compared to using 'WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 from ....)'?

Comment: @Sky21.86: the `exists` co-related subquery will be executed once for each row in `livetable` if `TestTable.userid` isn't indexed, this will be extremely expensive. The join reads both tables only once (although probably all rows from `testtable`). Processing many rows in "one go" is usually faster than doing a row-by-row processing. But you need to check the [execution plan](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-explain.html) to verify this.